In Nextjs 14, how can an image be imported dynamically from outside the app folder but as a subfolder of src?
Our app tree is structured as follow:
my-app|

      |src|

          |app
              |...  

          |portfolio|
                    |project_1
                    |project_2
                    |project_...

We can do this according their guide https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation#project-organization-strategies
A component called Project should return an Image component (more stuff in the future releases) by passing an object "project":
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Project({project}: { project: any }) {

    let defaultDescription = project.descriptions;

    let imagePath = project.path+"/preview/pic.png"

    return (
                <Image
                    src={imagePath}
                    alt={defaultDescription.title}
                    // placeholder="blur"
                    // blurDataURL={image.blurDataURL}
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                />
    );
}


The problem is that the image could not be imported simply like above, and neither using
import pic from 'path/to/image/pic.png'
because each projects has own path, although with the same name, and should be loaded dynamically.
It's not necessary use server side, we just need to create as static asset when building.
We made several attempts, research, and asking to AI (it is aware until 2022!).
Can anyone suggest how to achieve our goal?
